# SQL-Mysql Length varies

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

Hi all I am having a question regarding `Sql Server(Len)` and `Mysql(Length)`

I have written a sample script in `Sql Server` & `Mysql` as follows

```
Sql ---->select len('Experts ') 

Result ---->7

MySql ---->select Length('Experts ')

Result ---->8
```

Now I just made a change in query as follows

```
Sql ---->select len(' Experts') 

Result ---->8

MySql ---->select Length(' Experts')

Result ---->8
```

But why it is displaying different result in my first query..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server `LEN` function excludes trailing spaces as indicated in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx.

If you want the length with spaces included, try `LEN(<source> + 'x') - 1` where `<source>` is whatever you're trying to get the length of.

Comment: So `Sql` will not care about the spaces after string but will care about the spaces before string..

Comment: @User Yes. It treats space prefixes as significant and space suffixes as insignificant.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw - If space suffixes are insignificant, what happens when it becomes a prefix to some `Y`? Will it be like `'X ' + 'Y' = 'XY'`?